# How would you write a test for zip file generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I'm working on a service/workflow that takes a number of data files  associated with a `Project` and creates a zip of them. These files are managed by Carrierwave. I am using the native Rails TestCase/Minitest and was wondering what is the best way to test the generation of the zip file?

At the moment, the code that would grab the files and write them to a zip looks something like:

```
def generate_zip(project)
  project_tracks = project.project_tracks

  # base temp dir
  temp_dir = Dir.mktmpdir

  # path for zip we are about to create
  zip_path = File.join(temp_dir, "#{project.name}.zip")

  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(zip_path) do |zos|
    project_tracks.each do |project_track|
      path = project_track.track.path
      zos.put_next_entry(path)
      zos.write project_track.track.file.read
    end
  end
end
```

Initially my thought was to create the zip files and compare the bytes? Was wondering if this was a good idea or if there is a better/faster way to test this logic.

Comment: You could read that file back, extract the files and compare file contents.

Comment: Further to @Sergio's suggestion (`str == unzip(zip(str))` ?), If it's just the `zip` and `unzip` methods you wish to test you could apply that test to one or more ranomly-generated large files

Comment: Wonder if instead of testing the contents (which I feel tests more the implementation of rubyzip) I wonder if I can instead return an OutputStream and test things like number of files in the zip, names of those files, and somehow check for a non-zero size?

Comment: I would argue that testing the number of files, their names and that they have non-zero size tells you nothing if you aren't able to unzip the files anymore. On the other hand, when you are able to unzip the files do you really care about how they are stored in the output stream?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate on the entries of the file and compare the name:

```
Zip::File.foreach(result.path) do |entry|
   expect(entry.name).to eq('file1.txt')
end
```